# How to add Name and ID attributes to React FlatPickr?

Tags: reactjs, flatpickr

Is there anyway to add a name and ID attribute to Flatpicker? When I add it in the code, it gets removed when rendered in the browser.

**Code:**

`<Flatpickrdatetime type="monthSelect" id="startDate" name="startDate" onChange={this.handleChange} />`

**Rendered:**

`<input class="makeStyles-flatpickr-62 form-control input" placeholder="mm/yy" tabindex="0" type="text">`

**What I would like when rendered:**

```
<input class="makeStyles-flatpickr-62 form-control input" placeholder="mm/yy" tabindex="0" type="text" name="startDate" id="startDate">
```